# Conditional expectation $E(XY|X+2Y)$ of product of standard normals $X,Y$

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Basically the title. if $X$, $Y$ are independent $N(0,1)$ random variables, find the distribution of
$$E(XY|X+2Y)$$

I attempted the following:

Since $\text{Cov}(X-\frac{1}{2}Y,X+2Y)=0$, they are independent. So
\begin{align}
E((X-\frac{1}{2}Y)(X+2Y)|X+2Y) 
&=(X+2Y)E(X-\frac{1}{2}Y|X+2Y)\\
&=(X+2Y)E(X-\frac{1}{2}Y)\\
&=(X+2Y)(0-0)=0\\
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
E(XY|X+2Y)&=\frac{2}{3}(E((X-\frac{1}{2}Y)(X+2Y)|X+2Y)-E(X^2-Y^2|X+2Y))\\
&=\frac{2}{3}(E(Y^2|X+2Y)-E(X^2|X+2Y))
\end{align}
Now it is possible to find the densities of $E(X^2|X+2Y)$ and $E(Y^2|X+2Y)$, I could then convolve them to find an answer. But the computations involved are extremely tedious, and given that this is a question from the qualifying exam I assume there is an easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $U = X+2Y$ and $V=X-\frac{1}{2}Y$. Then $Y=\frac{2}{5}(U-V)$ and $X=\frac{1}{5}(U+4V)$.

$U \sim N(0, 5)$ and $V \sim N(0, 5/4)$ are independent.

$$E[XY \mid X+2Y] = \frac{2}{25} E[(U-V)(U+4V) \mid U]
= \frac{2}{25}(U^2 + 3UE[V] - 4 E[V^2])
= \frac{2}{25}(U^2 - 5).$$